# How to test Directive that serves only as a Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am using Jasmine to test my Angular components. I am able to test the functions, services and controllers well, however, how do i test a directive that only contains a template, for example:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template:   '<header>' +
                        '<p>' +
                            '<a href="http://someurl1.com/home" target="_blank">Home</a>' +
                            '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                            '<a href="http://someurl2.com/cookies" target="_blank">Cookies</a>' +
                            '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                            '<a href="http://someurl3.com/Terms" target="_blank">Terms</a>' +
                        '</p>' +
                        '<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>' +
                    '</header>'        
    };
});
```

---

I've tried something along these lines:

```
 describe('Directive: header', function () {
     beforeEach(module('headerDirective'));

     var element, scope;

     beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
         element = angular.element('<header>' +
             '<p>' +
                 '<a href="http://someurl1.com/home" target="_blank">Home</a>' +
                 '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                 '<a href="http://someurl2.com/cookies" target="_blank">Cookies</a>' +
                 '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                 '<a href="http://someurl3.com/Terms" target="_blank">Terms</a>' +
                 '</p>' +
                 '<p>Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>' +
             '</header>');

         scope = $rootScope;

         $compile(element)(scope);
         scope.$digest();
     }));

     it("should have the correct amount of <a>", function () {
         var list = element.find('a');
         expect(list.length).toBe(a);
     });
 });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Easier to help if at least have the base code for test.

Comment: @dcodesmith - added the test i was going to try... an attempt to count the correct number of <a>

Comment: What happens when you run the test?

Comment: @dcodesmith - receive this error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=headerDirective&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14

Comment: first error spotted ... change `scope = $rootScope;` to `scope = $rootScope.$new();`

Comment: You should inject your angular module too

Comment: @dcodesmith - arent i doing that through beforeEach(module('headerDirective'));

Comment: Check solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should inject load the angular apps module, not the directives.

```
describe('myDirective: ', function () {
    var service,
    scope,
    compile,
    element;

    //load the angular app module
    beforeEach(module('MyApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        element = angular.element('<my-directive></my-directive>');
        $compile(element)(scope);
        scope.$digest();
    }));

    it('should have 3 anchor tags', function () {
        expect(element[0].querySelectorAll('a').length).toEqual(3);
    });

    it('should have a Home link', function () {
        expect(element[0].querySelectorAll('a')[0].textContent).toEqual('Home');
    });

    // add more. Test for P tags.

});
```

**[JSFFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/a3fmzg8c/)**

Comment: thank you, this has helped solve the issue but also helped me pick up a few issues with my approach to testing

Comment: i imagine my approach is different in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29142600/jasmine-how-to-test-a-stylesheet-directive as my directive is a link in <head> ?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, it's still a directive and it has tags in it. So the same approach should work fine.

Comment: Ok i see. Updated the question with your approach now.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's not worth writing a test for this directive as it does not contain any logic.

Should you really want to test it anyway (i.e. it is critical to your application or users that the element is exactly what's in the template), you could always write a test that compiles the directive and checks whether it is replaced correctly by its template.

In that case the unit test would prevent any unwanted changes to the template. That's not the responsibility of a unit test though, an automated user test is better suited for the job.

Comment: I was under the same impression. A directive without any logic is difficult to test. I've added a basic example of the test i tried, an attempt to count the correct number of <a>

Comment: I agree with you. However, he might want to test for elements and tags. The idea is that if anything changes in the template. The test should fail.

Comment: @OamPsy that looks OK to me? Does it run? You're expecting the length of the list of elements to be `a`, I assume that should be replaced with a number?

Comment: @Anzeo - receive this error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=headerDirective&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.14

Comment: Yes, sorry, i replaced a with 3

Comment: Did you configure Karma correctly to include your sources?